# Error react-router-dom: <Route> elements are for router configuration only and should not be rendered

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I have been trying to solve this error for a while but everything I do not seems to work and I get the same error everytime:

> < Route> elements are for router configuration only and should not be
> rendered

This is the index.js code:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from "react-router-dom";

import App from './components/App'

import {Provider} from 'react-redux';

import store from './store/store';

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Router>
      <App />
    </Router>
  </Provider>, 
  document.getElementById("root"));
```

And the versions of the dependencies:

```
"react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.1",
    "react-router": "^3.2.6",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.1",
    "redux": "^4.0.5",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0"
```

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

Solved! I was importing wrong the Route in App.js. Instead of using react-router-dom, I was using react-router